# Is this possible to re-duplicate the hardware signal on Linux?

Tags: linux, hardware, unix, hacking

Since that every things is a file on the UNIX system. If I have a hardware, for example, a mouse, move from left corner to right corner, it should produce some kinds of file to communicate with the system.

So, if my assumption is correct, is this possible to do following things:

1. Capture the raw data, which is about moving mouse cursor from left corner to right corner?
2. Reduplicate the raw data, using a program, same producing speed, and data, in order to "redo" moving mouse cursor from left corner to right corner

Comment: Your assumption is not correct. E.g. TCP sockets are somewhat file-like, but do not appear in the file system.

Comment: Similar to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25601/how-do-mouse-events-work-in-linux

Comment: Does this need to be on the hardware level? The Xtest extension for X should enable you to replay mouse movement as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can capture "raw" mouse events using the /dev/input/* device nodes.  You can then replay those events by writing an application that interfaces with the uinput driver.

You can also do this with the XServer by subscribing to mouse events on the root window and using the xtest extension to replay the events.